# Can I get data from an NgRx service without updating cache?

Tags: ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I have my service and need to get data using `getWithQuery`, but I don't need NgRx store to be updated. I just need to get this data and use them in `subscribe` method.

I've tried different `EntityActionOptions.mergeStrategy` but cache is still updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible AFAIK @ngrx/data is bound to the store. 
If you just need the data, you can invoke the service directly.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngrx` store purpose is to be responsible for the app state. It means if you want to fetch something you dispatch an action that updates the store and then you select this data from the store.

If you want to fetch data directly skipping the store and select parts - it means you follow against `ngrx` purpose and perhaps you don't `ngrx` at all.

If you want to `ngrx` then consider writing you app in the way that it always puts data into the store if something is updated / fetched and to display the data it's always selected from the store.